# How to display specific data in specific div from database and pagination?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to display contents of database in specific DIV based on its type and pagination of every question of that tab to indicate whether the question is right or wrong using its question number.

This is my database content[Need to display data based on type column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/owPTv.png)

This is my website code where i want to display my questions...

```
<?php
session_start();
include('database.php');
$query = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM QUE;");
$row= mysqli_fetch_row($query);
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Online Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class = "tabinator">
      <h2>Timer:</h2>
      <div class = "clockdiv" align="right" style="color:red"></div>
      <div class = "finish"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="timer.js">

      </script>
      <br><br>

  <input type = "radio" id = "tab1" name = "tabs" checked>
  <label for = "tab1">Quant</label>
  <input type = "radio" id = "tab2" name = "tabs">
  <label for = "tab2">Verbal</label>
  <input type = "radio" id = "tab3" name = "tabs">
  <label for = "tab3">Reasoning</label>
  <input type = "radio" id = "tab4" name = "tabs">
  <label for = "tab4">Programing</label>
  <div id = "content1">
  </div>
  <div id = "content2">
  </div>
  <div id = "content3">
  </div>
  <div id = "content4">

  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to display the content in their respective content blocks. ( content 1 -> quant, content 2 -> verbal, content 3 -> reasoning, content 4 -> programming)

** About pagination: **

How to develop the pagination in the tab which indicates the question whether he is attempted or not by changing the colors?

Comment: If you want do without refresh you need to use AJAX

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are all data on page load from server so you can try below code to show content in specific div.

```
<?php 
    $Quant = '';
    $Verbal = '';
    $Reasoning = '';
    $Programing = '';

    foreach($row as $key => $value) {
        if ($value['type'] == 'quant') {
            $Quant += '
                <div>
                    <h3>' . $value['que_desc'] . '</h3>
                    <p>' . $value['ans1'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans2'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans3'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans4'] . '</p>
                </div>
            ';
        } else if ($value['type'] == 'verbal') {
            $Verbal += '
                <div>
                    <h3>' . $value['que_desc'] . '</h3>
                    <p>' . $value['ans1'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans2'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans3'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans4'] . '</p>
                </div>
            ';
        } else if ($value['type'] == 'reasoning') {
            $Reasoning += '
                <div>
                    <h3>' . $value['que_desc'] . '</h3>
                    <p>' . $value['ans1'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans2'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans3'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans4'] . '</p>
                </div>
            ';
        }
        } else if ($value['type'] == 'programing') {
            $Programing += '
                <div>
                    <h3>' . $value['que_desc'] . '</h3>
                    <p>' . $value['ans1'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans2'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans3'] . '</p>
                    <p>' . $value['ans4'] . '</p>
                </div>
            ';
        }
    }
?>

<div id = "content1">
    <?php echo $Quant; ?>
</div>
<div id = "content2">
    <?php echo $Verbal; ?>
</div>
<div id = "content3">
    <?php echo $Reasoning; ?>
</div>
<div id = "content4">
    <?php echo $Programing; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: May i know what should i keep in $value & $row variables.....

Comment: @Kuddus You don't have to put anything in them, they are auto populated in ```foreach``` loop. you have ```$row= mysqli_fetch_row($query);```, so in ```$row``` you have your database record as array.

Comment: sry i'm are getting  Illegal string offset 'type'  when i'm using $row= mysqli_fetch_row($query);.......................

coded as below:

`$query = mysqli_query($conn,'select * from que');
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);`

Comment: sry it's not working even i cleared the error and loop through it...........

Comment: Can you share the array record which is saved in $row variable?